# Why spring batch do not have reading boolean from file

Tags: spring-batch

I am wondering why Spring Batch file reader do not have simple feature of reading and automatically mapping boolean values from flat file (in the form of yes,no,true,false) and directly mapping to "boolean" type in the mapped object.

Absence of this feature, forces me to add another attribute of String type in the object. For example,

```
boolean aAllowed;
String aAllowedString;
```

Then ignore that aAllowedString when I am processing the object using something like @JsonIgnore. 
All this can be avoided if Spring Batch directly maps strings like yes, no, true, false, y, n to boolean values using Java's Boolean.parse methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of your `FieldSetMapper` and not something Spring Batch would want to support out of the box.  In your `FieldSetMapper`, you can do the logic to map a `String` value to whatever you want (including a `boolean`) so there is no reason to need both a `String` and `boolean` values in your item.

Comment: Thanks. It converts other values like Integer, Double from strings, then why not boolean ? :)

Comment: What would the boolean values be?  True/False, T/F, Yes/No, etc?  All the other options are very straight forward.

Comment: yes, true and false are supported by Boolean.parse itself plus the values you have listed. Or it can be configured on the bean.